# Iterating over a 2D List and removing elements or rows based on a conditional if statement - Python

Tags: python

I have a 2D array, the first column is a string of names and the later columns are their scores(integers). I am trying to iterate over the array and either remove any scores(single elements) that are greater than 100 and less than 0 or remove the entire row of from that array. I am them trying to then write the removed scores to a .txt file.

The first code below iterates over an array, when I run it to remove the actual row, it removes removes only one row that is over 100, I have to rerun it to remove more rows where the element is over 100 and it doesn't remove any rows where the elements are less than 0 (so the negative ones)the int() method doesnt seem to convert the negative elements from Str to Int when iterating to compare? .

Below is my array of scores;

```
    newArray = [['joe bloggs', '45', '46', '52', '83'],
 ['bobby uncle', '52', '45', '85', '63'],
 ['luke van', '69', '48', '45', '22'],
 ['lauren loo', '75', '24', '-65', '32'],
 ['heidi ho', '65', '7', '58', '14'],
 ['robyn cook', '23', '24', '51', '63'],
 ['cath roberts', '56', '85', '14', '74'],
 ['june jules', '58', '45', '26', '65'],
 ['dan nissie', '41', '56', '85', '45'],
 ['chris cooks', '24', '-15', '25', '75'],
 ['Kate Vander', '105', '23', '67', '1'],
 ['Luther rose', '55', '25', '207', '45']]






error = ""
for row in newArray:
    for index,col in enumerate(row):
        if col.isdigit() == True:
            if int(col)<0 or int(col)>100:
                error = error + col
                newArray.remove(row)

e.write(error)#I have a txt file set up for this.
```

I am also trying this code to remove just the single element. I read that removing one element causes issuess in the indexing which may not remove elements, so it is better to make a copy of the array, iterate over that, then remove it from the original array but it gives me an error.

I tried;

```
for row in copyOfArray:
    for col in row:
       if col.isdigit()== True:
           if int(col) < 0 or int(col) > 100:
              e.write(col)
              newArray.remove(col)
```

Essentially the results should be either:
#This one when I remove the row

```
newArray = [['joe bloggs', '45', '46', '52', '83'],
 ['bobby uncle', '52', '45', '85', '63'],
 ['luke van', '69', '48', '45', '22'],
 ['heidi ho', '65', '7', '58', '14'],
 ['robyn cook', '23', '24', '51', '63'],
 ['cath roberts', '56', '85', '14', '74'],
 ['june jules', '58', '45', '26', '65'],
 ['dan nissie', '41', '56', '85', '45']]
```

OR

```
#this when I remove just the single element:
newArray = [['joe bloggs', '45', '46', '52', '83'],
 ['bobby uncle', '52', '45', '85', '63'],
 ['luke van', '69', '48', '45', '22'],
 ['lauren loo', '75', '24', '32'],
 ['heidi ho', '65', '7', '58', '14'],
 ['robyn cook', '23', '24', '51', '63'],
 ['cath roberts', '56', '85', '14', '74'],
 ['june jules', '58', '45', '26', '65'],
 ['dan nissie', '41', '56', '85', '45'],
 ['chris cooks', '24', '25', '75'],
 ['Kate Vander', '23', '67', '1'],
 ['Luther rose', '55', '25', '45']]
```

I apologise for the size of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove single elements from the list, you can do this:

```
newArray = [['joe bloggs', '45', '46', '52', '83'],
 ['bobby uncle', '52', '45', '85', '63'],
 ['luke van', '69', '48', '45', '22'],
 ['lauren loo', '75', '24', '-65', '32'],
 ['heidi ho', '65', '7', '58', '14'],
 ['robyn cook', '23', '24', '51', '63'],
 ['cath roberts', '56', '85', '14', '74'],
 ['june jules', '58', '45', '26', '65'],
 ['dan nissie', '41', '56', '85', '45'],
 ['chris cooks', '24', '-15', '25', '75'],
 ['Kate Vander', '105', '23', '67', '1'],
 ['Luther rose', '55', '25', '207', '45']]

new_array = []

for row in newArray:
    numbers = [x for x in row if x.isdigit()]
    numbers_keep = [row[0]] + [n for n in numbers if int(n) >= 0 and int(n) <= 100]
    new_array.append(numbers_keep)
```

Which returns:

```
[['joe bloggs', '45', '46', '52', '83'],
 ['bobby uncle', '52', '45', '85', '63'],
 ['luke van', '69', '48', '45', '22'],
 ['lauren loo', '75', '24', '32'],
 ['heidi ho', '65', '7', '58', '14'],
 ['robyn cook', '23', '24', '51', '63'],
 ['cath roberts', '56', '85', '14', '74'],
 ['june jules', '58', '45', '26', '65'],
 ['dan nissie', '41', '56', '85', '45'],
 ['chris cooks', '24', '25', '75'],
 ['Kate Vander', '23', '67', '1'],
 ['Luther rose', '55', '25', '45']]
```

If you want to keep track of the removed items, you can use the following line, after you created the `numbers_keep` list. I'm not sure how you want the removed items to be formatted before writing it to a document, so I'll leave that to you.

```
diff = set(row) ^ set(numbers_keep)
```

Comment: Thats great Sandertjuhh, thank you. 

So I can understand your code, are you iterating through the original "newArray", then using an if statement to check if the element is an integer and appending it to a new list called "numbers". You are then iterating through the "numbers" list and appending the integers >= 0 and <= 100 and the first row of the original array to a new list called "numbers_keep". You are then appending this to the list "new_array". Could I ask, from your code, are you iterating the "numbers" list while iterating the outer loop of the original "newArray"?

Comment: @EL.M yep, that's exactly it :).